# Can't figure out how to use SharedPreferences in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to make in my app a stars counter and when the app is closed and reopened, the number of stars should remain the same, not going from 0 again. All I've done is this, but it doesn't work.

```
int correctGuesses = 0;

  String language1 = "";
  String language2 = "";
  String language3 = "";

  Widget buildGame() {

    final myController = TextEditingController();

    @override
    void dispose() {
      myController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    int nextNumber({required int min, required int max}) =>
        min + Random().nextInt(max - min + 1);

    int rowNumber = Random().nextInt(1);
    int columnNumber = nextNumber(min: 1, max: 10);
    final language = languageMatrix[rowNumber][0];
    final sentence = languageMatrix[rowNumber][columnNumber];

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget> [
          Image.asset('assets/GameLogo_2.png'),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.teal[200],
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
              ),
              height: 125,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    sentence,
                    style: const  TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(height: 20),
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget> [
                 Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 200,
                    //height: 70,
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.teal,
                      controller: myController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Enter a language',
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ),
                TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _incrementCounter();
                    if (counter >= 1 && counter <= 3 )
                        {
                          if (myController.text == language)
                          {
                            if (counter == 1)
                            {
                              language1 = language;
                              firstAttempt = myController.text;
                              correctGuesses++;
                            }
                            if (counter == 2)
                            {
                              language2 = language;
                              secondAttempt = myController.text;
                              correctGuesses++;
                            }
                            if (counter == 3)
                            {
                              language3 = language;
                              thirdAttempt = myController.text;
                              correctGuesses++;
                            }
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            if (counter == 1)
                            {
                              language1 = language;
                              firstAttempt = myController.text;
                            }
                            if (counter == 2)
                            {
                              language2 = language;
                              secondAttempt = myController.text;
                            }
                            if (counter == 3)
                            {
                              language3 = language;
                              thirdAttempt = myController.text;
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    if (counter == 3)
                    {
                      if (correctGuesses == 0)
                        {
                          showDialog<String>(
                              barrierDismissible: false,
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                                title: const Text('Your Score', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                                content: SizedBox(
                                    height: 250,
                                    child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: const <Widget>[
                                              Icon(Icons.star_border, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                              Icon(Icons.star_border, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                              Icon(Icons.star_border, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          Text('Sentence 1: $language1', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          Text('Sentence 2: $language2', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          Text('Sentence 3: $language3', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          const Text('Check your profile to see your total number of stars, or go back home and start a new round!', textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                                        ]
                                    )
                                ),
                                elevation: 24,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StartPage())),
                                    child: const Text('Home'),
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilePage()));
                                    },
                                    child: const Text('Profile'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                          );
                        }
                      if (correctGuesses == 1)
                        {
                          showDialog<String>(
                              barrierDismissible: false,
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                                title: const Text('Your Score', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                                content: SizedBox(
                                    height: 250,
                                    child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: const <Widget>[
                                              Icon(Icons.star, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                              Icon(Icons.star_border, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                              Icon(Icons.star_border, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          Text('Sentence 1: $language1', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          Text('Sentence 2: $language2', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          Text('Sentence 3: $language3', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          const Text('Check your profile to see your total number of stars, or go back home and start a new round!', textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                                        ]
                                    )
                                ),
                                elevation: 24,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StartPage())),
                                    child: const Text('Home'),
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      //setStarsNumber(correctGuesses);
                                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilePage()));
                                    },
                                    child: const Text('Profile'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                          );
                        }
                      if (correctGuesses == 2)
                        {
                          showDialog<String>(
                              barrierDismissible: false,
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                                title: const Text('Your Score', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                                content: SizedBox(
                                    height: 250,
                                    child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: const <Widget>[
                                              Icon(Icons.star, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                              Icon(Icons.star, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                              Icon(Icons.star_border, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          Text('Sentence 1: $language1', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          Text('Sentence 2: $language2', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          Text('Sentence 3: $language3', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                          Container(height: 15),
                                          const Text('Check your profile to see your total number of stars, or go back home and start a new round!', textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                                        ]
                                    )
                                ),
                                elevation: 24,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StartPage())),
                                    child: const Text('Home'),
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilePage())),
                                    child: const Text('Profile'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                          );
                        }
                    if (correctGuesses == 3)
                      {
                        showDialog<String>(
                            barrierDismissible: false,
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                              title: const Text('Your Score', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                              content: SizedBox(
                                  height: 250,
                                  child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: const <Widget>[
                                            Icon(Icons.star, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                            Icon(Icons.star, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                            Icon(Icons.star, size: 70, color: Colors.teal),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Container(height: 15),
                                        Text('Sentence 1: $language1', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                        Container(height: 15),
                                        Text('Sentence 2: $language2', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                        Container(height: 15),
                                        Text('Sentence 3: $language3', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                        Container(height: 15),
                                        const Text('Check your profile to see your total number of stars, or go back home and start a new round!', textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                                      ]
                                  )
                              ),
                              elevation: 24,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              actions: <Widget>[
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StartPage())),
                                  child: const Text('Home'),
                                ),
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilePage())),
                                  child: const Text('Profile'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                        );
                      }
                    }
                    myController.clear();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Guess'),
                )
              ]
            ),
          Container(height: 20),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100, vertical: 5),
              child: Container(
                height: 30,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.teal[200],
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget> [
                      const Text('Sentence 1/3: '),
                      Text(firstAttempt)
                    ]
                )
              )
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100, vertical: 5),
              child: Container(
                  height: 30,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.teal[200],
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget> [
                        const Text('Sentence 2/3: '),
                        Text(secondAttempt)
                      ]
                  )
              )
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100, vertical: 5),
              child: Container(
                  height: 30,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.teal[200],
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget> [
                        const Text('Sentence 3/3: '),
                        Text(thirdAttempt)
                      ]
                  )
              )
          ),
          Container(
            height: 10,
          ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }


  Future<int> getOldStarsNumber() async {
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int oldStarsNumber = (pref.getInt('keyStarsNumber') ?? 0);
    return oldStarsNumber;
  }

  Future<void> updateStarsNumber() async{
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int oldStarsNumber = await getOldStarsNumber();
    int starsNumber = correctGuesses + oldStarsNumber;
    pref.setInt('keyStarsNumber', 0);
  }
```

This is from the first class I am using, and this is where I calculate the number of stars.

```
class ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {

  int? starsNumber;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setStarsNumber();
  }

  Future<void> setStarsNumber() async {
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    starsNumber = pref.getInt('keyStarsNumber');
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My profile, coming soon'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Icon(Icons.star, size: 200, color: Colors.teal,),
            Text('$starsNumber', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 100)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the second class, where I get that number of stars and putting it in a Text. With this code, the total number of stars always remain 0, and I dont know what to do. The correctGuesses variable is from the widget build above, which does work...

All I am thinking is that maybe is that correctGuesses variable looses its value. I think I'm 100% wrong.

Comment: check 'starsNumber' number value. it's sum always may be become 0. and store 0 every time you open app.

Comment: Something is really really bad in my code...i even wrote
```
pref.setInt('keyStarsNumber', 0);
```
...and the result is still the old one...it doesn't update

Comment: Welcome to SO @Cornel. Would you please [edit] your question and also share the code that includes the `correctGuesses`.

Comment: Hello. Thank you, i ve done that

Comment: There should be a call to `updateStarsNumber(correctGuesses)` somewhere in the game to actually save the stars but I don't see it. Isn't that what's missing?

Comment: yup, dont have that :)

Comment: I've done it. All I needed was to call those functions. I am stupid and at the beginning. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with your code is that you're initializing the instance of shared preferences over and over again with each update in your updateStarsNumber function. Try to have an app-wide instance of shared preferences. You can initialize it in your main function, call it prefs, and inject it wherever it's needed.

Basically, only call await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); once in the app.

Comment: I don't know where to put this 'final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();'. I took it out from the 2 functions and it says that The await expression can only be used in an async function. The problem is that I don't know in what async function

Comment: Please try to provide an actual code sample depicting the solution for clearer understanding. Thank you !!